# How can decode this json data that exported at Haumi API?

Tags: json, decode, xiaomi

First, thanks to read this question.

I am developing a website that show statistic chart on health data from wearable device; specially Miband 7
Yesterday, I found some API that bring health data from Haumi Server. It run correctly but "data" of this response is encoded.

I am trying to decode this data. But i coudn't. :(
Here is the json data.

The full data can find this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3Zx1I6jV9WL2jCBi9TpbzyB8rhA_fDn/view?usp=sharing

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "uid": "5077903424",
            "data_type": 0,
            "date_time": "2023-07-26",
            "source": 264,
            "summary": "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",
            "uuid": "1868505a-98b8-4e28-98dc-a4ea62b1981e",
            "data": "fgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAcwkAcBUAUA4AUAMAUAAAUA0AUCIAUB0AUB8AUCwDUAsAUAUAUA8AUBUAUAMAUA0AUBAAUAAAUAAAUAUAUAAAUBMAUBEAUAAAUAAAUAgAUAAAUAoAUAIAUAEAUA8AUAkAUAAAUAAAUAcAUBEAUBIAUAsAUAkAUAwAUAIAUAMAUAgAUBkAUBYAUAEAUAAAUAAAUAAAUAYAUB8AUAoAUBkAUBAAUBIAUB0AUAsAUBcAUDQAUBsAUEUuYBcAQBIAYBMAYB8HYDQQYDYYfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAAfgAA",
            "data_hr": "/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7/////////////YP///////////1v///////////9J////////////S////////////1j///////////9k/////////v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+"
        },
```

First I try to decode on base64.
`summary` is worked but, others is not.

I think others are saved like form of some DBMS. Because APIs were found in `Zepp Life`;Android Applicaiton (and this application use SQLite3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Data that base64 decoded `data_hr` are heart rate per one minute.

The length of data are 1440. It is one day.

Furthermore, I compared my hr and decoded data. So I found those are same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbsh4.png)

| date | hr(DEC) | hr(hex) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 74 | 4a |
| 00:05 | 88 | 58 |
| 00:10 | 78 | 4e |
| 00:15 | 80 | 50 |
| 00:20 | 82 | 52 |
| 00:25 | 63 | 3f |
| 00:30 | 73 | 49 |
| 00:35 | 78 | 4e |
| 00:40 | 77 | 4d |